# Kubernetes Ingress of Type LoadBalancer not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I installed [Kubernetes NGINX Ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) in kubernetes cluster. When i am trying to access the micro service end via Ingress Controller its not working as expected

I am deploying on AWS Instance, i followed the documentation from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/index.md)

I have two Spring boot application which has context path as **/customer** running on port 9000 and **/prac**  running on port 8000 and third one is nginx running on port 80

I have executed these commands to create ingress controller of Type LoadBalancer

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.30.0/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.30.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/service-l4.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.30.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/patch-configmap-l4.yaml
```

Pods Running

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE               NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress-controller-7f74f657bd-rh5fj   1/1     Running   0          23h     10.32.0.10      ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
kube-system     coredns-6955765f44-8wkwl                    1/1     Running   0          2d23h   10.32.0.3       ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
kube-system     coredns-6955765f44-w79bh                    1/1     Running   0          2d23h   10.32.0.2       ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
kube-system     etcd-ip-172-31-11-145                       1/1     Running   0          2d23h   172.31.11.145   ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-11-145             1/1     Running   0          2d23h   172.31.11.145   ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-11-145    1/1     Running   0          2d23h   172.31.11.145   ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-proxy-6ktz2                            1/1     Running   0          2d23h   172.31.34.24    ip-172-31-34-24    <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-proxy-mrlt6                            1/1     Running   0          2d23h   172.31.11.145   ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-11-145             1/1     Running   0          2d23h   172.31.11.145   ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
kube-system     weave-net-5bmvb                             2/2     Running   0          2d23h   172.31.11.145   ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
kube-system     weave-net-gl7xz                             2/2     Running   1          2d23h   172.31.34.24    ip-172-31-34-24    <none>           <none>
practice        customer-6d467cbc57-q6l6h                   1/1     Running   0          46h     10.32.0.8       ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
practice        customer-6d467cbc57-rx7zt                   1/1     Running   0          46h     10.32.0.5       ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
practice        ngtest-6c5ff8c7df-lmbhz                     1/1     Running   0          45h     10.44.0.1       ip-172-31-34-24    <none>           <none>
practice        ngtest-6c5ff8c7df-pvv4w                     1/1     Running   0          45h     10.32.0.9       ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
practice        prac-865d49687b-q8hss                       1/1     Running   0          23h     10.32.0.11      ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
practice        prac-865d49687b-wxkxr                       1/1     Running   0          23h     10.44.0.2       ip-172-31-34-24    <none>           <none>
practice        some-mysql-7896cfbb4c-kgnxf                 1/1     Running   0          46h     10.32.0.7       ip-172-31-11-145   <none>           <none>
```

Service Running

```
NAMESPACE       NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
default         kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>          443/TCP                      2d23h
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx      LoadBalancer   10.110.197.3    18.221.167.75   80:32414/TCP,443:31112/TCP   23h
kube-system     kube-dns           ClusterIP      10.96.0.10      <none>          53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       2d23h
practice        customer-service   ClusterIP      10.106.14.223   <none>          9090/TCP                     46h
practice        ngtest             ClusterIP      10.109.249.63   <none>          80/TCP                       45h
practice        prac-service       ClusterIP      10.110.96.199   <none>          8000/TCP                     46h
practice        some-mysql         ClusterIP      None            <none>          3306/TCP                     46h
```

After installing ingress nginx, I have created ingress controller which is of type Loadbalancer.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: practice-ingress
  namespace: practice
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec: 
  rules:
  - host: kdhut.com
    http: 
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: customer-service
          servicePort: 9090
        path: /customer
      - backend:
          serviceName: prac-service
          servicePort: 8000
        path: /prac
      - backend:
          serviceName: ngtest
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

I created Classic Load Balancer, but the load Balancer health check is not passing, health check i am pointing to port 80, but its showing out of service.

[image]

I tried to check with Cluster IP, but its show Empty response from the server, please help me on this.

```
root@ip-172-31-11-145:/home/ubuntu# kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
default         kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>          443/TCP                      2d23h
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx      LoadBalancer   10.110.197.3    18.221.167.75   80:32414/TCP,443:31112/TCP   23h
kube-system     kube-dns           ClusterIP      10.96.0.10      <none>          53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       2d23h
practice        customer-service   ClusterIP      10.106.14.223   <none>          9090/TCP                     46h
practice        ngtest             ClusterIP      10.109.249.63   <none>          80/TCP                       46h
practice        prac-service       ClusterIP      10.110.96.199   <none>          8000/TCP                     46h
practice        some-mysql         ClusterIP      None            <none>          3306/TCP                     46h
root@ip-172-31-11-145:/home/ubuntu#
root@ip-172-31-11-145:/home/ubuntu#
root@ip-172-31-11-145:/home/ubuntu#
root@ip-172-31-11-145:/home/ubuntu# curl http://10.110.197.3/
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
root@ip-172-31-11-145:/home/ubuntu# curl http://10.110.197.3/prac/
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
root@ip-172-31-11-145:/home/ubuntu#
```

Comment: did you create the classic load balancer manually?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu yes  i created it manually and the i set the external IP in ingress-nginx

Comment: you should not create it manually...the second yaml that you applied should create it automatically

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu this static/provider/aws/service-l4.yaml should have created it, but its not created. now what needs to be done ?

Comment: Okay lets go with manual...have you created egress and ingress security group? Have you configured node ports as instance port in LB?

Comment: For Ingress Security group any specific port needs to be opened, So far i have security group where port 80, 30000 - 32767, 8001,8080, 6443, 2379 - 2380, 22,443, 10250 - 10252 are allowed from all IP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209936/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-arghya-sadhu).

Comment: @OhHiMark yeah i am able to fix the issue, it was due to proxy protocol, but still i am stuck with ssl

Comment: @Kuldeep Could you please explain what did you do in order to make it work as an answer? If you encountered another problem than please ask about it in a separate question. That way it will be more clear for everyone to work with.